# Azure Functions static SqlConnection - right way to scale?

Tags: azure, static, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, sqlconnection

I'm using Azure Functions with queue triggers for part of our workload. The specific function queries the database and this creates problems with scaling since the large concurrent number of function instances pinging the db results in maximum allowed number of Azrue DB connections being hit constantly.

This article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections lists HttpClient as one of those resources that should be made static.
Should database access also be made static with static SqlConnection to resolve this issue, or would that cause some other problems by keeping the constant connection object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should database access also be made static with static SqlConnection

Definitely not.  Each function invocation should open a new SqlConnection, with the same connection string, in a using block.  It's not really clear how many concurrent Function Invocations the runtime will make to a single instance of your application.  But if it's more than 1, then a singleton SqlConnection is a bad thing.

I wonder exactly which [limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits) you're hitting in SQL Database, the connection limit or the concurrent request limit?  In either case I'm a bit surprised (not a Functions expert) that you get that many concurrent function invocations, so there might be something else going on.  Like you're leaking SqlConnections.

But reading the Functions docs, my guess is that the functions runtime is scaling by launching multiple instances of your function app.  Your .NET app could scale in a single process, but that's apparently not the way Functions works.  Each instance of your Functions app has it's own ConnectionPool for SQL Server, and by default each ConnectionPool can have 100 connections.

Perhaps if you sharply limit the Max Pool Size in your connection string, won't have so many connections open.  When you hit the Max Pool Size, new calls to SqlConnection.Open() will block for up to 30 seconds waiting for a pooled SqlConnection to become available.  So this not only limits the connection use for each instance of your application, it throttles your throughput under load.

Comment: Does this recent introduction of DI in functions change anything? They specify SqlConnection as something that should be of Singleton scope. How would you execute SqlConnection as a singleton in functions... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

Answer (score 1):

You can use the configuration settings in [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json) to control the level of concurrency your functions execute at per instance and the [max scaleout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#websitemaxdynamicapplicationscaleout) setting to control how many instances you scale out to. This will let you control the total amount of load put on your database.

Comment: The notes for that setting specify "This setting is a preview feature - and only reliable if set to a value <= 5" My database allows 200 connections before failing. Do you know if it's possible to set the limit for an Azure Function to somewhere in between?

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, [the documentation has been updated with some information about the SQL connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#sqlclient-connections) stating:

> Your function code may use the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server (SqlClient) to make connections to a SQL relational database. This is also the underlying provider for data frameworks that rely on ADO.NET, such as Entity Framework. Unlike HttpClient and DocumentClient connections, ADO.NET implements connection pooling by default. However, because you can still run out of connections, you should optimize connections to the database. For more information, see SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET).

So, [as David Browne already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50768887/352640), you shouldn't make your `SqlConnection` static.