# Limit number of azure functions running concurrently

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I have this setup on Azure.

- 1 Azure Service Bus
- 1 Sql Azure Database
- 1 Dynamic App Service Plan
- 1 Azure function

I'm writing messages in the service bus, my function is triggered when a message is received and writes to the database.

I have a huge number of messages to process and I have this exception:

> The request limit for the database is 90 and has been reached

I dig here on SO and in the docs and I found this answer from Paul Battum: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50769314/1026105

> You can use the configuration settings in host.json to control the level of concurrency your functions execute at per instance and the max scaleout setting to control how many instances you scale out to. This will let you control the total amount of load put on your database.

What is the strategy to limit the function, since it can be limited on:

- the level of concurrency your functions execute at per instance
- the number of instances

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in to using the [Durable Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview) for Azure Functions where you can control the number of orchestrator and activity functions. You will need to change your design a little but will then get far better control over concurrency.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "durableTask": {
    "HubName": "MyFunctionHub",
    "maxConcurrentActivityFunctions": 10,
    "maxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions": 10
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00"
}
```