# What is the most efficient way of using service bus together with SQL Server within Azure functions?

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm working on an Azure Function, in which I need to read data from a Service Bus queue and write it to an Azure SQL table.

My issue is: the Service Bus part is reactive and is being triggered for each new message arriving to the queue, while the whole business of setting up and opening Azure SQL connection only needs to bet set up once, and preferably before-hands.

Currently, I have my function as such:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

namespace SbTrigger01
{
    public static class SbTrigger02
    {
       static SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        [FunctionName("SbTrigger02")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("BasicQueue", Connection = "servicebus00ghjs1968_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            builder.DataSource = "myazuresql001968.database.windows.net";
            builder.UserID = "sqladminwek1968";
            builder.Password = "@Myazuresql00sdjhj1968";
            builder.InitialCatalog = "mySampleDatabase";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                string query = "INSERT INTO [SalesLT].[messages] (message) VALUES(@Message)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(myQueueItem);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", myQueueItem);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            log.LogInformation($" {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect, this this code forces the SQL connection to be defined and opened for each new service bus message, which is quite terrible.

Is there a better way of structuring this code, so the SQL connection is only declared and opened once, and only the `INSERT` statement is being executed for each new service bus message?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50766009/59563

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Functions static SqlConnection - right way to scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766009/azure-functions-static-sqlconnection-right-way-to-scale)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks!

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg Congratulations you get the answer. Thanks Sean Feldman and Ian Kemp. I help you post it as answer. You can think about mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations you can get the answer from this link:

[Azure Functions static SqlConnection - right way to scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766009/azure-functions-static-sqlconnection-right-way-to-scale)

I help you post it as the answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.

Thanks Sean Feldman and Ian Kemp.