# Azure function support for connection pooling or any other way to reuse same instance of db

Tags: azure, azure-functions

As AWS Lambda support Connection pooling as shown in the [Link](https://spot.io/blog/best-practices-serverless-connection-pooling-database/).

As per my requirement i will use trigger function with kafka. But the request to database is gonna happen so frequent that it can use high percentage of cpu. So to avoid that i want to use connection pooling or any other way to use same instance of database context.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a new C# SqlConnection object on each function invocation has no bad performance implication because ADO.NET manages a SQL connection pool already for you. So if you close a connection, it is [just put back into the pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) which means you can use a connection like this:

```cs
using System.Data.SqlClient;

const string connectionString = "..."; // Better get this from a Key Vault

[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public static void Run(...)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  
    {  
        connection.Open(); // Get a connection object from the pool
        // Execute queries on connection
    }  
}
```

Similarly for Python and pyodbc, connection pooling is enabled by default here and a call to `pyodbc.connect()` can make use of the pool:

```py
import azure.functions as func
import pyodbc

connectionstring = "DRIVER=[...];SERVER=[...]"

def main(events: List[func.EventHubEvent]):
    connection = pyodbc.connect(connectionstring)

    with connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT [...] FROM [...]")
            columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
            result = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
            print(result)
    connection.close()
```

There is also a JavaScript example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections).

*Edit: Changed this answer after a comment by @kiranpradeep*

Comment: Don't forget that this is pooling within a single function host not across.

Comment: This answer contradicts another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50768887) for almost same question. That answer appears to be from an MS employee.